# Send data only through mobile data on android phones when wifi is on

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

Is it possible to programmatically route a request through mobile data even when the wifi is on and connected to the internet?

My app needs to call a service provided by the operator which is only available through mobile data and I don't think it's user-friendly to ask for turning off the wifi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

specifically, it has a function that allows you to do what you want.

```
 5 Provide an API that allows applications to request and select networks for their data traffic
```

you request a network, and then setDefaultNetwork( API before 23) or use bindProcessToNetwork for  API >= 23  .

you   probably want to request a network with int   TRANSPORT_CELLULAR capabilities (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.html)