# If i use private sim internet and not connecting with global internet then in mobile application what settings i need to do?

Tags: android

I got a task where I cannot use public sim internet and I need to use private sim connect to its own server then what settings I need to do while creating a mobile application for them.... It is for both android and ios but I am specifically concerned with android right now.

For example: IF I need to call any API to work then are there any specific settings through which I can do it or not???

Comment: What is a private sim internet?

Comment: like organization have its own separate internet service ... its not connected to public internet ...

Comment: Yes i know private internet. But what has it to do with a sim card? Are they private mobile provider too?

Comment: yes ... and i want to know what i need to do if i want to work on calls from their server .... is there any specific settings there or it will be done normally as in public internet...

Comment: do you have any idea about this kind of thing ....

Comment: It's just an IP network. You don't need to do anything special. You do, of course, need to be aware that services like push notifications and cloud based services may not work, unless the organisation has allowed access via their firewall.

Comment: @blackapps it isn't a private "Internet", it is just a private network. Mobile providers can provision a service so that it connects directly to an organisation's internal network rather than to the carriers internet service. It is called private APN (access point name)

Comment: @Paulw11 wow you got me bro... 100% u r saying right ... yeah that will be provided by the company ....

Comment: @Paulw11 also one more thing if I need to call any API then all processes will be the same as calling API on the internet from ios and android mobile application... or it requires some extra work ??? just calling API i am little bit worried

Comment: @Paulw11 Have your worked on it ?? or you see working for this?

Comment: It's just an IP network.  It will rely on IP addressing, DNS and routing just like the Internet.  There is no difference to a mobile device on your home WiFi accessing an API you are hosting on your laptop on your home WiFi.

Comment: yeah so you mean to say is instead of http:www.xyz.com url i need to call through ip address thats it.... thats what i get.... every other things are same as normal application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send data only through mobile data on android phones when wifi is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190105/send-data-only-through-mobile-data-on-android-phones-when-wifi-is-on)